# Usando Spyder, ¿cómo saber cuáles de los hilos (threads) abiertos son propios de Spyder, y cuáles son hilos huérfanos?

Tags: python, spyder

Cuando ejecuto este código para saber cuántos hilos tengo abiertos desde el intérprete Spyder me da como salida 7.
¿Cómo hago para saber si son hilos propios de Spyder, o si fue que por error en un código que ejecuté con anterioridad donde abría varios hilos, dejé hilos sin cerrar?

Lo anterior para saber si estos hilos son por malos códigos del pasado y están consumiendo recursos.

Código para saber hilos abiertos:

```py
import threading

def main():
    print(threading.active_count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```